# Angular Typescript Filter Collection without altering original content to hide/show columns

Tags: angular, typescript

I am adding the hide/show columns where a click on 1 specific column will hide/show several columns. I tried using [hidden] and *ngIf but the way the HTML is written, the data is not rendered but the columns are still showing. Basically blank columns. I wanted to hide and move all the columns to the left but there are several blank columns still showing that does not look good.

Next, I tried to filter the collection, but using .filter changes the original collection like the following

```
var filteredColumns = this.myData.columns.filter(f => f.show == true);
```

If I had 12 columns and execute the .filter line, it will reduce my collection in the original this.myData.columns from 12 to 8. I tried to instantiate the filterColumns and allocates its own memory like so

```
filterColumns: FilterColumn[] = [];
```

and do a copy like so

```
 this.copyCollection = Object.assign([],  this.OriginalCollection);
```

and after the filtering, the original collection was alway altered.

Is there a way to filter the columns so I have a copy of the filterColumns without altering the original collection?

Comment: did you try using this.OriginalData.columns.slice() and then filter?

Comment: Hi, @c0micrage you can get a reference from here: 
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#2-define-the-column-templates

Comment: use two different array's